# Where does Azure Artifacts code get stored in On-Premise solutions?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-artifacts, package-management, azure-devops-server

We have an On-Premise version of TFS 2018. I am interested in utilizing the packages (now Azure Artifacts) feature within TFS. I am wondering where the source code of the packages that are built and deployed gets stored. For example, if I build a version of an NPM package, does that source code live on our on-premise server or somewhere in the cloud?

Answer (score 2):

The answer: It depends.

If you publish it to an internal feed, [it's stored in your TFS database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/architecture/sql-server-databases?view=azure-devops).

If you publish it to an external feed, it's stored there.

Comment: This is the right answer. The source code (in your Git or TFVC repository) is also stored in your TFS database.

Comment: Since the question specifically asking about how it works on-premise, doesn't that imply that it isn't hosted externally?  Do you know the details about how it is stored in the TFS database?  Seems like hosting all build artifacts would greatly increase the on-premise database size?  Is there any guidance about managing that for on-premise?

Answer (score -2):

The source code is present under Code.

[image: 1]

The artifacts that are generated after building the code is present under Pipelines->Build

[image: 2]

Click to the build marked red in above.

[image: 3]

The build view will have the Artifact option to access the build artifacts.

[image: 4]

You can download the artifacts from above by clicking the three dots.